# Change Fragment TextView from Activity using ViewPager

Tags: java, android

I have an Activity that retrieves data from a web API after a button click and saves it in a custom Stats object. In my view I have a TabLayout with ViewPager. The problem is that I cannot change the TextViews from my Fragment after the Activity has retrived all the data, I always get a NullPointerException.

I've tried a lot of things, but none of them seem to work and I don't know what to do.

Here is my Activity:

```
public class StatsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public TextView textStats, responseView;
    public EditText usuario;
    public ProgressBar progressBar;
    public ImageButton buscar;
    public TabLayout tabLayout;
    public TabItem tabSolo, tabDuo, tabSquad;
    public ViewPager viewPager;

    String idUsuario, user;
    Stats soloStats = new Stats();
    Stats duoStats = new Stats();
    Stats squadStats = new Stats();
    Typeface TF;
    PageAdapter pageAdapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.stats);

        textStats = findViewById(R.id.textStats);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        responseView = findViewById(R.id.responseView);
        usuario = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        buscar = findViewById(R.id.searchButton);
        tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabSolo = findViewById(R.id.tabsolo);
        tabDuo = findViewById(R.id.tabduo);
        tabSquad = findViewById(R.id.tabsquad);
        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.pager);

        TF = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font/BurbankBigCondensed-Bold.ttf");

        pageAdapter = new PageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        viewPager.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        setCustomFont();

        LinearLayout tabStrip = ((LinearLayout) tabLayout.getChildAt(0));
        for(int i = 0; i < tabStrip.getChildCount(); i++) {
            tabStrip.getChildAt(i).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }

        tabLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        responseView.setText("");
        responseView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

        textStats.setTypeface(TF);
        responseView.setTypeface(TF);

        buscar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                user = usuario.getText().toString().trim();
                new getPlayerId().execute();
            }
        });

    }

    class getPlayerId extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        private Exception exception;

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            responseView.setText("");
        }

        protected String doInBackground(Void... urls) {

            user = user.trim();

            try {
                // getting data

                    return stringBuilder.toString();
                }
                finally{
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage(), e);
                return null;
            }
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
            if(response == null) {
                response = "THERE WAS AN ERROR";
            }
            Log.i("INFO", response);

            try {
                JSONObject object = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(response).nextValue();

                //Parsing JSON and setting soloStats

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO CHANGE MY FRAGMENT TEXTVIEW

            //SoloFragment solo = (SoloFragment) pageAdapter.getItem(0);
            //solo.getStats(soloStats);
        }
    }
}
```

My fragment code:

```
public class SoloFragment extends Fragment {

    TextView textVictorias, textTop2, textTop3, textPartidas, textKills, textPuntos, textMinutos, textJugadores;

    public SoloFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_solo, container, false);

        textVictorias = v.findViewById(R.id.textVictorias);
        textTop2 = v.findViewById(R.id.textTop2);
        textTop3 = v.findViewById(R.id.textTop3);
        textPartidas = v.findViewById(R.id.textPartidas);
        textKills = v.findViewById(R.id.textKills);
        textPuntos = v.findViewById(R.id.textPuntos);
        textMinutos = v.findViewById(R.id.textMinutos);
        textJugadores = v.findViewById(R.id.textJugadores);

        return v;
    }

    public void setStats(Stats stats){

        textVictorias.setText(stats.getTop1());
        textTop2.setText(stats.getTop2());
        textTop3.setText(stats.getTop3());
        textPartidas.setText(stats.getPartidas());
        textKills.setText(stats.getKills());
        textPuntos.setText(stats.getPuntos());
        textMinutos.setText(stats.getMinutos());
        textJugadores.setText(stats.getJugadores());

    }

}
```

I'm always getting the NPE on setText inside setStats, and I don't know how to solve this, hope anyone can help me! Thanks!

Comment: Set your tab fragments when you will get a response in activity and pass your data using bundle.

Comment: You can use Realm for this. When you retrieve data, save data with Realm and get saved data from fragments with Realm Listeners. Or you can use EventBus libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your onPostExecute method

```
      //HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO CHANGE MY FRAGMENT TEXTVIEW        
      if (pageAdapter.getFragment() != null) {
          pageAdapter.getFragment().getStats(soloStats);
      }
```